# Laravel 8 PUT routes return 404

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm trying to update data in the database via API but it returns error 404 not found in postman.

api.php

```
    // PUT update citizen from NIC
Route::put('updateCitizen/{nic}',[CitizensController::class, 'updateCitizen'] );
```

controller.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Citizen as ModelsCitizen;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB as FacadesDB;

class CitizensController extends Controller
{
    public function updateCitizen(Request $request, $nic)
    {

        $citizen = FacadesDB::table('citizens')
            ->where('nic', '=', $nic)
            ->update(['options->enabled', true]);

        return response()->json($citizen);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you change the API route as following?

```
Route::put('update-citizen/{nic}',[CitizensController::class, 'updateCitizen']);
```

and run the following command.

```
php artisan route:cache
```

and try with the following URL - `{baseUrl}/api/update-citizen/{an-existing-nic}`

Comment: I tried .
now its giving me a different kind of error (500 Internal server error)

Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `citizens` set `0` = options->enabled, `1` = 1 where `nic` = 970173099V) in file

Comment: Something wrong with your this line - ->update(['options->enabled', true]); It can be ->update(['field_name', true]);. Makesure you have the field in your database table.

Comment: yes @lyathurai you were correct !
That was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

why you dont use a api resource approach insted, looks much more faster to write to imo.

```
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources
```

Otherwise  use more '`LIKE`' as string operator for the where clause

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the update query.
in the query where,

```
->update(['options->enabled', true]);
```

has to be changed as,

```
    ->update($request->all());
```

to update the all the vlaues in the uri to the database columns.

Answer (score -1):

top of your contoller put:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

then use:

```
$citizen = DB::table('citizens')
         ->where('nic',$nic)
         ->update(['options->enabled', true]);
```